# Always modify returned values from laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a model, `Post` that has no methods defined within it.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use DB;

class Post extends Model
{

}
```

From a controller, I make calls to that model like:

`return view('pages.post', ['post' => Post::where('url_route', '=', $url_route)->first()]`

This works fine, but I now want to format the date column that is returned from that request, every time that model is called. Is there a way to modify the returned array without defining a new method?

I am new to Laravel to thanks for the help. Just trying to figure out the most efficient way of doing things within the framework...

Comment: you can find what are you looking for here [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators)

Answer (score 2):

If your model has `$timestamps` set to true, the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are natively a `Carbon` instance.

This means you can format the date in the view like this as a basic example:

```
$post->updated_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

`Carbon` instances allow you to leverage its extensive api as you can see at http://carbon.nesbot.com

If you would like to do the same for another field other than `created_at` and `updated_at`, you can add an extra property in your model:

```
protected $dates = ['added_on']
```

The fields you specify in the array will be treated as `Carbon` instances.

Comment: oh great, didnt know that! Yeah I was going to modify them with carbon, haha.

Comment: Also I believe instead of `getDates()` you can create a property like `protected $dates = ['added_on']`.

Comment: @user2094178 Overriding the `$dates` property is the proper/expected way to do this. If you override the `getDates()` method as you have shown, your `created_at` and `updated_at` fields will no longer be Carbon instances.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I've never noticed it since my `BaseModel` has `getDates()` containing `created_at` and `updated_at`.